# Google Cloud Video intelligence and embedded video content

Tags: youtube, google-cloud-platform, artificial-intelligence, vimeo, video-intelligence-api

Does Google Cloud Video intelligence work with embedded video content from Vimeo or YouTube. Will it be able to create tags, see faces etc... since the content is not directly uploaded?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible, as it says in the [main page](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/):

> It quickly annotates videos stored in Google Cloud Storage, and helps
>   you identify...

Moreover, in the REST API [docs](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/reference/rest/v1/videos/annotate#request-body) it specifies, for the `inputUri` field:

> Input video location. Currently, only Google Cloud Storage URIs are
>   supported, which must be specified in the following format:
>   gs://bucket-id/object-id (other URI formats return
>   google.rpc.Code.INVALID_ARGUMENT). For more information, see Request
>   URIs. A video URI may include wildcards in object-id, and thus
>   identify multiple videos. Supported wildcards: '*' to match 0 or more
>   characters; '?' to match 1 character. If unset, the input video should
>   be embedded in the request as inputContent. If set, inputContent
>   should be unset.

There is a [group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cloud-videointel-discuss) for discussing Cloud Video Intelligence API features and this question was asked [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-videointel-discuss/M59-K-wwXd8).